# AWK - Processing a large CSV (13 Billion Rows) for duplicate data based on multiple columns (composite key) results in Out of Memory error

Tags: csv, awk

I have a CSV with 13 billion rows in it, 719GB in size. There are some duplicated rows in the CSV. The CSV has three columns, sample data below:

```
tag,time,sensor_value
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
```

Each instance of the composite key `tag` and `time` should be unique. In words, a `tag` can have one value at a given `time`.

I have tried the following:

```
awk -F, '!seen[$1,$2]++' data.csv > data_UNIQUE.csv
```

Kernel eventually kills the above process due to `Out Of Memory` error. My system specifications are as follows:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900K CPU @ 3.70GHz
128GB RAM
2TB NVME
```

How can I successfully process this CSV with awk?

EDIT:
The desired output CSV would have no duplicated data, and per discussion in the comments, it would make sense to sort before passing to `awk` so we only look at adjacent rows.

Desired output:

```
tag,time,sensor_value
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
```

Comment: Much better but by using the same value for every `sensor_value` field we can't tell if you wanted the first or last value printed for each pair of keys. You should use different values for every 3rd field in your sample input, state if you want the first or last (or something else?) 3rd field printed for each pair of duplicate keys, and then show that same thing in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any versions of the mandatory Unix tools awk, sort, and cut, this will sort the output by the 2 key values:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { print (NR>1), NR, $0 }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -t, -k1,1n -k3,4 -k2,2n |
cut -d, -f3- |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { key = $1 FS $2 }
    key != prev {
        print
        prev = key
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
tag,time,sensor_value
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
```

This will preserve the input order for the output:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { print (NR>1), NR, $0 }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -t, -k3,4 |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    { key = $1 FS $3 FS $4 }
    key != prev {
        print
        prev = key
    }
' |
sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2n |
cut -d, -f3-
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
tag,time,sensor_value
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_3_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_1_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-03-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-01-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
"CHLR_2_SP","2020-08-31 10:27:13.736248","59.76000213623047"
```

We decorate the input using awk (printing `NR>1`) to identify the header line (`0`) separately from the rest (`1`) instead of using `head -n 1 test.csv && tail -n +2 test.csv | sort...` because the latter requires the input file to be opened twice and so won't work if the input is coming from a pipe.

We also decorate with `NR` so that given 2 duplicate keys the value printed will be the first one that occurred in the input (or we could revers the sort on that field so the last value gets printed if that's preferable). We could instead use GNU sort for `-s` but then the solution becomes unnecessarily GNU-only.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton. The sample file I tested with gave the output I was looking for. Through the comments & different approaches, I learned quite a bit about the external details associated with this issue.

Comment: While monitoring the script's process on my large file, it is observed to be quite slow to execute. CPU usage is about 100% on a single core and memory usage is almost none. Its been running about 45 minutes. Would that be something I can speed up with parallelization, or is the particular nature of these operations not a good fit for it?

Comment: You'd have to ask a different question about that specific thing and tag it with `parallel` or something to get someone familiar with such tools to answer. The part of the script that's most likely to be taking a while is the `sort` so you could google something like "sort parallel speed" first.

Comment: After some Googling and benchmarking, I have found that making use of `-S80G` (80GB memory buffer) and `--parallel=18` (18 threads) parameters for the sort have considerably sped things up. I was able to process 1M rows in just under 5 seconds. I think my job will be done in 20 hours. Not ideal, but certainly better since I can see that my server's resources are being put to use. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html

Answer (score 1):

Sort based on the multi-column key. Then a single pass through the sorted file can eliminate duplicates by looking only at adjacent records. There is no need to store the entire file in memory.

EDIT: To compare adjacent records and ignore duplicates (WARNING: UNTESTED CODE):

```
($1 $2) == prev { next }
{ prev = ($1 $2); print $0 }
```

The first line compares the concatenation of the first two fields to the previous record and skips to the next record if the key fields of the current record and previous record match. The second line is executed only if the current record differs from the previous record; it saves the key in the first two fields, then prints the record.

Comment: As suggested, first sort the file: `(head -n 1 test.csv && tail -n +2 test.csv | sort -t, -k1 -k2) > data_SORTED.csv`, while ignoring the header. As for the single pass with awk, what would it look like?

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: In general you can't create a unique string by concatenating 2 other strings, for example `a bc` and `ab c` would both concatenate to `abc`. In this particular case you'd get away with it since the input strings are surrounded by quotes and so have a separator built into them but it's bad practice in general and causes people reading your code to have to wonder if there's something about the input data that'd make it not be broken so you should use `$1 FS $2` everywhere instead of just `$1 $2`.

Comment: @Ajility in addition to making it so you can't take input from a pipe as discussed in my answer, with `(head -n 1 test.csv && tail -n +2 test.csv | sort -t, -k1 -k2) > data_SORTED.csv` you'd be spawning a subshell, when you don't need to do that, you'd use `{...}` instead of `(...)` to just group the commands.